# How to listen for "any speech" in VoCon Hybrid and capture what was said

Tags: voice-recognition, bnf

Part of my task is to make a system that simulates dictating and sending a text message using Vocon.

I tried using the <...> aka "garbage" rule like this:

```
#BNF+EMV2.1;
!grammar messageInput;
!start <messageInput>;

<messageInput> : cancel | <...>;
```

Unfortunately that means I don't get what was said, but rather I get the "<...>" as a result.

How can I make Vocon listen to any speech, but report back to me what was said?

(If the changes need to be done in the C code rather than the speech input grammar, I'm also interested in that)

Comment: To my dear downvoters: care to explain why you're downvoting? 

As far as I can see, this is a perfectly valid question, and one for which I am still searching for an answer. I posted what I tried and what the result was. What can I further clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Nuance tech support 5 days ago and finally a couple of hours ago, here's what they answered:

> What you described (returning any spoken text) is dictation -- not
>   grammar-based speech recognition.
>
> To perform dictation with Vocon Hybrid, you use the server-based or
>   cloud-based service via the NMSP or HTTP interface.
>
> Please search for "dictation" in the Vocon Hybrid 4.8 documentation.

So summarising, it is not possible to do it the way I was intending to; it requires a different mechanism.